# User gets instantly disconnected after connection successful on a chrooted SSH

Tags: ssh, debian, openssh, chroot

I configured a jail with Chroot in SSH following [this tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/chrooted-ssh-sftp-tutorial-debian-lenny).

I found [another question on StackOverflow dealing with the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361203/openssh-session-closed-after-login-with-chroot), however the answers didn't work for me either.

The `auth.log` file contains the following:

```
Mar 16 18:36:06 *** sshd[30509]: Accepted password for thenewone from x.x.x.x port 49583 ssh2
Mar 16 18:36:06 *** sshd[30509]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user thenewone by (uid=0)
Mar 16 18:36:07 *** sshd[30509]: lastlog_openseek: Couldn't stat /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
Mar 16 18:36:07 *** sshd[30509]: lastlog_openseek: Couldn't stat /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
Mar 16 18:36:07 *** sshd[30509]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user thenewone
```

My `sshd_config` file contains the following:

```
Match User thenewone
    ChrootDirectory         /home/thenewone
    AllowTcpForwarding      no
    X11Forwarding           no
```

My `/home/thenewone` directory is owned by `root:root` and contains the chrooted system (all files but `/home/thenewone/home/thenewone` owned by `root:root`)

I don't understand why the connection is successful then simply close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem found: some binaries dependencies were missing, even for the shell associated with the chrooted account...

Shell failed to load --> disconnection!

If you are experiencing the same trouble as mine, use `ldd <binary>` to find all needed dependencies in the chroot jail